# Access external class files in java using eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a class file to handle the GUI which is SampleGUI.class. I want to use that into my java project. I have created a folder named ClassFiles in root directory. I put the SampleGUI.class inside that folder. I went to project properties ->Libraries->Add Class Folder. Then i tried to call that class inside my new class created inside the project like

new SampleGUI ( length, width) ;. But it gives me the error "SampleGUI cannot be resolved to a type". Do i need to import anything? How do i procees with this situation?

Comment: Is SampleGUI on root package?

Comment: yes, you need to import if it's in a **different package** from your source files

Comment: If SampleGUI is in the root package, it can only be used form within the root package. It would be better that your clases be in a real package structure.

Comment: No SampleGUI is not on root package, its in a different folder. How do i import it?

Comment: If it is not in the root package, you need to import the folder that has root package. E.g. if class is com.xyz.app.SampleGUI , you need to add the folder that contains "com" folder and not the folder that contains SampleGUI.class

Comment: Can anyone tell me, if I have one class file SampleGUI.class, how do I put it in a project? My java file is in project1->src->Mp1->test.java

Comment: @Shamit Verma I have done until this part, can you please see am I doing it right?This is the folder structure i have now. "Project1(This is project folder)->P1(Source Folder)->MP1(Package)->Test1.java". "Project1(This is project folder)->P1(Source Folder)->ClassFiles(Package)->SampleGUI.class(I pasted the class file in here from external source)". After this I went to project properties->Libraries->Add Class folder and i added ClassFiles folder. Then i can see it in Refrenced Libraries as P1/ClassFiles->(default package)

Comment: What is the package of SampleGUI and what is the complete (absolute) path of SampleGUI.class? Also can you post contents of .classpath from the Eclipse project that is trying to import the class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If SampleGUI is in a different package, you'll need to import it.

e.g.

```
import ClassFiles.SampleGUI;
```

where ClassFiles is the package name.

If SampleGUI is your own, and you have the .java source file, you can add SampleGUI to the ClassFiles package, if it isn't already, by adding the following line to the top of SampleGUI:

```
package ClassFiles;
```

Comment: I have no access to the SampleGUI.java file. I just have the class file SampleGUI.class. What I need to do is to access it inside my test.java class. Can you tell me how do I need to put inside a package?

Comment: If, for example, you had a file Test.java in the package com.testing (and so com.testing.Test), you need to go to Java Build Path > Libraries > Add Class Folder and add the directory that contains 'com', which contains the directory 'Testing', inside of which is Test.java.

Comment: Where do i need to put SampleGUI.class file? I am confused. I am new to java, so please dont get irritated by my silly questions. I have one .java file and .class file. Where should i put both of this. Can you guide me from step1?

Comment: I have done until this part, can you please see am I doing it right?This is the folder structure i have now. "Project1(This is project folder)->P1(Source Folder)->MP1(Package)->Test1.java". "Project1(This is project folder)->P1(Source Folder)->ClassFiles(Package)->SampleGUI.class(I pasted the class file in here from external source)".  After this I went to project properties->Libraries->Add Class folder and i added ClassFiles folder. Then i can see it in Refrenced Libraries as P1/ClassFiles->(default package)

Comment: The package that SampleGUI is in is set in the SampleGUI.class file  with a line such as "package P1.ClassFiles;". Putting this file in a directory called "Tests" would not make it be in the Package "Tests".

Because SampleGUI doesn't seem to have a package set (and so is default package), you can't import it.

Answer (score 1):

I have create a Jar file using the command

jar cf jar-file input-file(s)

And I imported those jar files into my project and it all worked fine.